# Direct object pronoun placement with dual verbs

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe

I am having some trouble deciding where to put the object pronoun in constructions with more than one verb. As far as I can gather, when a modal verb (devoir, pouvoir, vouloir) is concerned, the pronoun always comes after the modal verb and before the main verb:

*Pour pouvoir **le** faire, nous devons...*

*Tu devrais **le** casser...* etc.

However, I have encountered sentences in which there is a dual verb construction, with non-modal auxiliary verbs such as faire, in which the object pronoun precedes both verbs. I saw on a grammar website that this is always the case with faire, but I was wondering if there is an underlying rule here, or at least a list of verbs where this applies (perhaps all dual verb constructions with non-modal verbs are like this?). Examples:

*Il **les** fallait cacher...
Ça vous **la** fera perdre...
Pour **les** aller mettre sur sa tombe...*

If you could refer me to a source where this is explained in detail, that would be appreciated as well. I have looked through multiple grammar books without finding a satisfactory explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. il les fallait faire, Il les fallait cacher, Pour les aller mettre sur sa tombe...  : this is 19th century language that is not used any more.
2. Ça vous la fera perdre : this is modern day French ; the place of the pronoun is exceptional for two verbs (laisser, faire).

> ([JM Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/pronom-place.html)) Exceptions
>
> La règle concernant la place des pro­noms faibles devant un infinitif dépen­dant d’un au­tre ver­be n’a que peu d’ex­cep­tions :
>
> **a.** […]
>
> **b.**  **Faire + in­fi­ni­tif**, **laisser + in­fi­ni­tif**: le pro­nom se place devant le ver­be prin­ci­pal faire ou laisser :
>
> • Il a laissé tomber **le vase**. → Il **l**’a laissé tomber.
> • Je lui ai fait apprendre **le texte** par cœur. → Je **le** lui ai fait apprendre par cœur.
> • Je laisse **les enfants** jouer seuls. → Je **les** laisse jouer seuls.
> • Il faut laisser **le produit agir**. → Il faut **le** laisser agir.
> •  Pour la réception, elle compte se faire faire **une nouvelle robe** chez une cou­tu­riè­re. → Elle compte s’**en** faire faire une chez une cou­tu­riè­re.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! The quotes with falloir and aller are indeed from Stendhal (Le rouge et le noir); one of my methods (and motivations) for improving my French is to read classic works, but this looks like one of the instances where they can cause confusion. I appreciate the reference.